# How are photons effected by gravity?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, photons, mass, mass-energy

If we use E²=m²c⁴+p²c², and we know mass of photon is zero, and  they have momentum but why aren't they affected by gravity.

Comment: It's E² on the left, and they are affected by gravity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $E = m^2c^2 + p^2 c^2$ is restricted to Special Relativity.

However, in classical physics we have
$$
\vec{F} = m \vec{a},
$$
and
$$\vec{F} = m \vec{g},$$
whence
$$
m \vec{a} = m \vec{g}.
$$
This can be written as
$$
m \big( \vec{a} - \vec{g}\big) = \vec{0}.
$$
From a mathematical point of view we have
$$
\big( m = 0 \big) \vee \big( \vec{a} - \vec{g} = \vec{0} \big).
$$
But from a physical point of view we could have
$$
\vec{a} - \vec{g} = \vec{0}.
$$
This means that *all bodies* satisfy
$$
\vec{a} = \vec{g}.
$$
As $\vec{g}$ is due to gravity, a photon *IS* accelerated as well...

Comment: As commented in the original question, it's $E^2$, and it should be $m^2c^4$.